# Are the errors for DML statements (select, insert, etc.) recorded somewhere for AWS Keyspaces (Cassandra)

Tags: amazon-keyspaces

I'm getting a vague error back from AWS Keyspaces that I'm trying to troubleshoot, but it looks as though AWS only stores DDL statement logs for Keyspaces in Cloudtrail, and not DML.  I can see the 'error count' in my dashboard in the AWS Console for Keyspaces, but no details about the errors themselves.  **This is NOT a question about what might be wrong with my insert statements**, or otherwise, and only **a question about whether these errors are recorded somewhere in AWS**.

I understand that there are other ways to approach this from a troubleshooting standpoint, but I want to first establish whether DML related server-side errors are logged by AWS somewhere, or could if they could be, given extra configuration.

In case someone has encountered something similar, here is all the detail I'm given back from the error itself:

```
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.ServerError: java.lang.AssertionError
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have more of a stack trace?

You can improve observability with these cloudformation "cloudwatch" templates. Provide the keyspace or table and the template with generate some dashboards for you.
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-keyspaces-cloudwatch-cloudformation-templates